# Using symbology for representing start and end (polygon / point) in QGIS

Tags: qgis-3, symbology, multi-polygon

I have records with two geometry columns per record. I have been looking at different options to show them in QGIS:

1. Create two layers (one for start and one for end)
2. Create a multipolygon that merges the two (start and end) polygons

The issue with #1 is that it doesn't show the link between the two zones within a single record. The problem with #2 is that I am not sure how to show the difference between the start and end polygon through symobology.

Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: Please provide a screenshot showing a single entry and the polygon on the map canvas.

Comment: @Erik I have added the screenshot.

Comment: Your screenshot doesn't provide any hint on the connection between the polygons.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The QGIS **geometry generator** symbol layer type is well suited for this, allowing you to keep one QGIS feature and display both of its geometries (or more).

For instance, suppose the (default) geometry assigned to each feature is the starting one (either since you digitized the feature in QGIS that way, or since you specified it as *the* geometry when importing the layer. And suppose the ending polygon is in an attribute `EndGeometry`, stored as WKT.

In this case, use the `Single symbol` renderer and first specify the symbology for your start polygon. Then **add** a symbol layer (+ icon on the right) and specify layer type `Geometry generator`, geometry type `Polygon`. The large expression window underneath will initially contain the expression `$geometry`, which is a shortcut for "the current main geometry",the starting polygon for you. Change that expression to `geom_from_wkt("EndGeometry")` and style the symbol sublayers underneath it in the symbol tree to display the end polygon as you wish.

You will need to modify with the right attribute name, of course. And you may need to change the expression if the end polygon is stored in another way than WKT.

Finally, you could create yet more geometry generator symbol layers and use more complicated expressions to link the two. For instance, the following (as a LineString geometry type) would allow you to style a line joining the centroids of the polygons to visually link them:

```
make_line(centroid($geometry),geom_from_wkt("EndGeometry"))
```

**Editing to add:** You can do all of this also with the Categorized or Graduated renderer (etc), with multiple layers wherever you then define your (compound) symbol. However, you will need to enter it separately under each category (or similar). So it will likely be more efficient to use the Single Symbol renderer, define the symbol layers (including with geometry generator) only once, and then use data-driven overrides to change the size or coloring based on the attribute you were intending to Categorize or Graduate over.

Comment: Thanks, this worked.Interestingly, even though my postgis table that was used as the input for this layer had two geometry columns (startgeom and endgeom), when I added the layer for the startgeom, I had to use geom_from_wkt("endgeom") for the Geometry Generator. Is there a shortcut for accessing the geometry column directly?

Comment: @sridharraman, `$geometry` refers to the (dominant) geometry column, in binary form. If you say `geom_to_wkt($geometry)` you would get its WKT, if you needed it.

Comment: thanks. 

I wonder if this is too much to expect. But is there a way to add this Geometry Generator along with Graduated Symbols? If I want to shade the polygons based on a value in the table?

Comment: I have added to the answer regardig Graduated and Categorized renderers.

Comment: What do you mean by "data-driven overrides to change the size or coloring based on the attribute"? Is it rule-based symbology? Because when I try that, it removes the Single Symbol layer.

Comment: Apologies, I realise what you mean. It's the option next to the fill colour and other style elements.